# INSERT: when should I not be using the APPEND hint?

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert batches of data in an Oracle table, with an `INSERT` statement, namely:

```
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM all_objects;
```

I've come across the [APPEND](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/append-hint) hint, which seems to increase performance in some cases.

Are there situations where it might decrease performance and it should not be used?

Thanks

Comment: If you will often use append load and at the same time data from target table will be often deleted you'll get a slow reading from table (TABLE ACCESS FULL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The append hint does a direct path insert, which is the same direct path insert used by SQL*Loader, when specified.  For large datasets, you should see dramatic improvements.

One of the main caveats you need to be aware of is that one of the reasons it is so fast is that it inserts all new rows past the high water mark.  This means that if you are frequently deleting rows and re-inserting, a conventional insert could potentially be better than a direct path because it will reclaim the freed space from the deleted rows.

If, for example, you had a table with 5 million rows where you did a `delete from` followed by a direct path insert, after a few iterations you would notice things slow to a crawl.  The insert itself would continue to be nice and speedy, but your queries against the table will gradually get worse.

The only way I know of to reset the HWM is to truncate the table.  If you plan to use direct path on a table with minimal dead rows, or if you are going to somehow reset the HWM, then I think in most cases it will be fine -- preferable, in fact, if you are inserting large amounts of data.

Here's a nice article that explains the details of the differences:

https://sshailesh.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/conventional-path-load-and-direct-path-load-simple-to-use-in-complex-situations/

A final parting shot -- with all Oracle hints, know everything you can before you use them.  Using them haphazardly can be haphazard to your health.

Answer (score 2):

I think performance will may be  decreased in the special case if  your select retrievs only one or a small number of rows.
So in this I would use not the append hint. The OracleBase article describes very well the impact of the APPEND hint. He also provides the link to the [manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55049)
There are 3 different situations:

1. The APPEND hint will not have any effect because it will be silently ignored. This will happen if a trigger is defined on the table or a reference constraint or under some other circumstances.
2. The append hint will raise an error message or a statement following the statement with the APPEND hint will raise an error message. Her you have two possibilities: either you remove the APPEND hint or you split the transaction in two or more separate transactions.
3. The append hint will work. Here you will get better performance if you use the APPEND hint (except if you have only a small number of rows to insert as stated at the beginning). But you will also need more space when using the append hint. The insert will use news extents for the data and not fill them in the free space of the existing extends. If you do a parallel insert each process uses its own extents. This may in a lot of unused space and be a drawback in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

It might negatively affect performance if you are using it for inserting small sets of data.

That's because it will allocate new space every time instead of reusing free space, so using it with multiple small sets can fragment your table which may result on performance issues.

That hint is a good idea for large inserts scheduled for times where usage is low.

Comment: I think that this hint is good for data which will not be deleted because you'll get 'holes' (append write after HWM). But if you only keep data append  is good solution.